# I need my date/time label to not have the date in it. Anyone know how for IOS?

Tags: ios, time, swift3, nstimer

This label works perfectly, although i don't need the date in it, I'm going to have the date in a separate label. I just need a label that displays time. This is what i have for a date/time label:

```
func updateTime() {
    TimeLabel.text = DateFormatter.localizedString(from: Date(), dateStyle: DateFormatter.Style.medium, timeStyle: DateFormatter.Style.short)

}
```

Swift 3, IOS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this will help in **SWIFT 3** its working in my code let me know you still have some issue .

```
 static var TIME_FORMAT: String = "hh:mm a"
 var date = Date()
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
            formatter.dateFormat = TIME_FORMAT
            let time = formatter.string(from: date)
            TimeLabel.text=time
```

Comment: thank you! do you know how to make my time freeze or stop counting? i need to know what time i opened the view controller

Comment: @DanielG Create another question and ping its link here .I am not able to understand your question  in one liner or explain  your question with code.

Comment: @DanielG .  I think create a static variable in helper or constant class  example : openTimeABCVC and   update its value with time  on viewload of your viewcontroller  and use that time whereever you want to update .

Comment: haha i didn't understand that! but i appreciate the effort :) i think for "repeats" on this code i wrote "false":

      Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.1, target: self, selector:       Selector("updateTime"), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)

Comment: //Initialize
   var checkUpdate = false
    var myTimer: Timer? = nil

//when you call timer
self.checkUpdate=true
self.myTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 5.0, target: self, selector: #selector(self.countDownTick), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

//function to stop timer 
 func countDownTick() {
        if (checkUpdate==true) {
            myTimer!.invalidate()
            myTimer=nil
            checkUpdate = false
        }        
    }

Answer (score 2):

Just change the style to `.none`:

```
func updateTime() {
    TimeLabel.text = DateFormatter.localizedString(from: Date(), dateStyle: DateFormatter.Style.none, timeStyle: DateFormatter.Style.short)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To remove the date, just set the date style to `none`!

```
TimeLabel.text = DateFormatter.localizedString(
    from: Date(), dateStyle: .none, timeStyle: .short)
```

The [docs](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/dateformatter.style/1411037-none) for `.none` says that

> Specifies no style.

I think this is why you're confused. You thought `none` just represents a date without style, i.e. not "stylish" and it will still appear in the string. But that is not true. `none` literally makes the date disappear.

Comment: thank you! is there a way to not make it live or counting up with the actual time? so is it possible if my time were to freeze once i open up the view controller with that time label?

Comment: There is! @DanielG First get how many seconds are left in the current minute. Update the label after that many seconds. After that, do a timer that updates the label every minute.

Comment: thank you! i ended up setting "repeats" to "false"


         Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.1, target: self, selector:     Selector("updateTime"), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)